# For $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ a measure space and $f$ a measurable function prove that

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory

For $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ a measure space and $f$ a measurable function prove that:

For all $t>0$, $$\mu(\{ x\in X: |f(x)|>t\})\leq \frac{1}{t^2}\int f^2 d\mu $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$A_t:=\{ x\in X: |f(x)|>t\}$$ Then, since $f^2\ge 0$ you have that $$\int_X f^2 dμ =\int_{A_t}f^2 dμ + \int_{X\backslash A_t} f^2 dμ \ge \int_{A_t}t^2 dμ +0=t^2 μ(A_t) $$

Comment: You beat me to it by a minute. :-) Let me just point out for the OP that this is a special case of what is known as [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).